# Use wp_mail without loading themes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm doing a integrating between two sites using cron on linux and i need to use wp_mail to send an email.
So i'm using the [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) recommendation to integrate

```
<?php 
    /* Short and sweet */
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

wp_mail won't work on the entire script using this integration option, I read that has something about the action `plugins_loaded` that only is loaded with the templates.

I cant find a way to load only the necessary plugins on this page to send the e-mail.

thanks.

Comment: use SMTP email , bez many time mail function is not working so you can chose alternate that is SMTP

Comment: what do you mean with smtp, is a function of wp or you meant to use directly phpmailer

Answer (score 0):

use from your theme

```
<?php      
    require('../../wp-load.php');
?>
```

hope it will work..